# should I make methods to compare two objects or an arbitrary number of objects?

Tags: java

I've seen a lot of methods, like:

`Integer.compare(int, int)`

`Arrays.compare(Object, Object)`

`Arrays.equals(byte, byte)`

And all of them accept just two argument values. My point here is:

> Is there any conventions about making these methods? Why not making them accept and arbitrary number of arguments?

As a beginner, this question got me thinking a lot. I'm currently solving the Eight Queens puzzle in Java and I got to this:

I need to make a method to check if the queens are at the same diagonal. Currently, the method has occupied 75 lines of code. I'm taking an arbitrary number of `Queen` objects, like:

`public static boolean anyAtTheSameDiagonal(ChessBoard board, Queen... queens)`

Would be better if I just compared two queens?

`public static boolean areAtTheSameDiagonal(Queen queenOne, Queen queenTwo)`

And then executing this method to all queens? To see if any of them could attack another?

My Eight Queens problem was just an example, should I make methods to compare just two things or **it depends on the case**?

Comment: Your use case seems to be completely different than comparing 2 objects to determine their order (which is what those compare methods are for). So i don't quite see where you see the connection and what you think should maybe be similar in those 2 different use cases. You are trying to do something different (determining if at least 2 objects fulfill a certain condition) and that has little to do with comparing 2 objects to determine their natural order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that if you are using reduce-like functions,
which is basically what you have in the Java stream (Stream.allMatch, Stream.anyMatch and Stream.reduce), you are much better with the atomic two-object comparison function (or conflicting in your case). You can compose any type of comparison/conflict check using these functions very easily.

Furthermore, your 75 lines function seems kinda bloated, in the 8 queens problem (or n-queens), if you use the backtracking algorithm, all you need to do is try to add a queen at a certain point of time and check if it conflicts with other queens. You never need to check conflicts between all the possible queen pairs.

Regarding the implementation, I think that an arithmetic approach is very elegant. use the coorinates deltas to determine if they have the same diagonal.

```
public static boolean areQueensOnSameDiagonal(Queen queen1, Queen queen2) {
    // Calculate delta of x and y coordinates
    int deltaX = Math.abs(queen1.x - queen2.x);
    int deltaY = Math.abs(queen1.y - queen2.y);
    
    // Queens are on the same diagonal if delta of x and y coordinates are the same
    return deltaX == deltaY;
}
```